# jQuery hide, change content, show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to chage a div content with ajax, but before hide it and after the change, show it with jQuery animation.

My current code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuItem", function(){
    var contentName = $(this).attr("name");
    $( "#content > div" ).hide(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: contentName,
            dataType: 'html',
            success : function(responseText){
                $("#content").html(responseText);
                $("#content").show(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But it isn't working, because when html method invoked, the new content sudden appear. 
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `$("#content")` element is always visible. Before ajax call you are hiding a div inside `#content` -> `$("#content > div")`.

You can hide the `$("#content")` before adding content.

```
$("#content").hide().html(responseText).show(1000);
```

or

```
    $("#content").hide(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: contentName,
            dataType: 'html',
            success : function(responseText){
                $("#content").html(responseText).show(1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: time can also be passed into hide() to further ease the animation

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuItem", function(){
    var contentName = $(this).attr("name");
    $( "#content > div" ).hide(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: contentName,
            dataType: 'html',
            success : function(responseText){
                $("#content").hide().html(responseText).show(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide content first :

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuItem", function(){
    var contentName = $(this).attr("name");
    $("#content > div" ).hide(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: contentName,
            dataType: 'html',
            success : function(responseText){
                $("#content").hide();
                $("#content").html(responseText);
                $("#content").show(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```